# Entity-Framework -> MySql gives 'Function evaluation timed out.'

Tags: mysql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I having a weird problem with Entity Framework with MySql database.

Here's the code that I've got.

```
public class testbase
{
    private testEntities db = new testEntities();

    public IQueryable<post> GetRecords()
    {
        return db.record;
    }
}
```

Here record is a table in my database and this could should return all the rows in the table. I have only one row in there and when I do a db.record.Count(), I get 1.

But when I try to retrieve the rows themselves I get 'Function Evaluation timed out'.

What's happening? Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: "Function evaluation timed out" sounds like the message the Visual Studio debugger produces in the watch window. Is that where you see it, or is it an exception?

Comment: That's right, I am seeing it in the debug window. Do you mean to say that my code will produce results if it's not in debug? It's not an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, this turned out to be a dud question. Ben M was right. Some googling revealed: -

1. EF does not behave well while debugging due to some issues in VS debugger. You get a 'Function evaluation timed out'.
2. Things work swell when you try the code without debugging.

I was testing as I go for my new EF+MySql+ASP.Net.MVC app, and since I am a n00b at all three I didn't realize that.

I haven't deleted the question yet because there for others like me. It's on the community to decide whether to let this question survive or go.

I pronounce this question officially a dud.

Comment: I don't think this question is a dud.  I've been having a ton of issues getting my Silverlight + RIA Services + EF + MySQL app to work.  I'm a "noob" as well, so I appreciate any insight I can get.  Now if I can only figure out how to debug EF without debugging....wierd.