# LINQ - join with Group By and get average

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

SQL:

```
SELECT DeptId,avg(Marks) FROM StudentTb s
JOIN StudInDepartment d on s.StudentId = d.StudentId
GROUP BY DeptId
```

Convert into Linq:

```
  var deptRpts =         from s in this.ObjectContext.StudentTb
                         join d in this.ObjectContext.StudInDepartment on s.StudentId equals d.StudentId  
                         group s by d.DeptId into grp
                         select new {
                             DeptId = grp.Key,
                             AverageMarks = grp.Average(ed=>ed.Marks)
                         };
```

Got an empty result list.

While expanding the result-set in debug mode.Its shows error **function evaluation timed out**

Need help on this.

Comment: do you get a non-empty list when you ommit the group by and only join?

Comment: @Jeroen If i removed the join its shows result(non-empty).

Comment: and with the join it doesnt? do your 2 tables really share studentids? otherwise joining them would always give an empty list and you might want to consider a left-join.

Comment: Yes both table share studentid.Sql query runs fine.

Comment: how much data are we talking about here? I don't see any problems with your code anyways.

Comment: Did you trace/profile the generated SQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The query works fine as is, at least in my mock up I just threw together ... it may have something to do with how the database is structured....in my mock up I have the studentID as a foreign key to the StudInDepartment (ha!) table and even this simplified query works ok

```
var deptRpt2 = from d in ctx.StudInDepartment
   group d by d.DeptId into grp
   select new {
      Dept = grp.Key,
      AverageMarks = grp.Average(ed=>ed.StudentTb.Marks)
   };
```

The message you received "function evaluation timed out" may be the Visual Studio [debugger issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141571/entity-framework-mysql-gives-function-evaluation-timed-out), can't help you there, theres other threads off stackoverflow that discuss it as well.