# LINQ - multi join with Group by and get average

Tags: c#, linq, join, average

I'm trying to write this select in LINQ but Im not successful to fix it for long time. I also tried [LINQ - join with Group By and get average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929136/linq-join-with-group-by-and-get-average) but it doesn't work in my code. It is obviously that I'm wrong.

SQL:

```
SELECT name_type, AVG(t.price) as avgPrice FROM type tp
JOIN location l ON l.ID_type = tp.ID 
JOIN event e ON e.ID_location = l.ID
JOIN ticket t ON t.ID_event = e.ID
GROUP BY tp.name_type
```

LINQ:

```
var q3 = from l in db.location
join tp in db.type on l.ID_type equals tp.ID
join e in db.event on l.ID equals u.ID_location
join t in db.ticket on e.ID equals t.ID_event 
group tp by new {Type_name = tp.type_name} into grp
select new
{
     Type_name = grp.Key.type_name,
     avgPrice = grp.Average( x => x.ticket.price)
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems:

1. There is an error in the second join—I believe `u.ID_location` needs to be `e.ID_location`.
2. I think you are grouping on the wrong entity, try grouping by `t` instead of `tp`.
3. You don't need the anonymous type in the `group by`.

Try this:

```
var results = 
     from l in db.location
     join tp in db.type on l.ID_type equals tp.ID
     join e in db.event on l.ID equals e.ID_location
     join t in db.ticket on e.ID equals t.ID_event 
     group t by new tp.type_name into grp
     select new
     {
          Type_name = grp.Key,
          avgPrice = grp.Average(x => x.price)
     };
```

If you happen to have navigation properties set up between your entities, this would be a lot easier. It's pretty hard to tell how the entities are *supposed* to be related, but I'm thinking something like this would work:

```
// average ticket price per location type
var results = 
    from t in db.ticket
    group t by t.event.location.type.type_name into g
    select new
    {
         Type_name = g.Key,
         avgPrice = g.Average(x => x.price)
    };
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var results = db.ticket.GroupBy(t => t.event.location.type.type_name)
                       .Select(g => new 
                               { 
                                   Type_name = g.Key, 
                                   avgPrice = g.Average(x => x.price) 
                               });
```

Comment: Thank you soo much ! It works perfectly :)  Now I can go to try more difficult selects...